# How can I represent the below json schema using Java Objects?

Tags: java, json, oop, methods, jackson

I have the below Json Schema.

```
 {  
       "name":{  
          "first":{  
         "attributeValue":"firstName",
         "attributeType":1,
         "dataType":1
          },
          "last":{  
         "attributeValue":"lastName",
         "attributeType":1,
         "dataType":1
          }
       },
       "age":{  
          "attributeValue":"age",
          "attributeType":1,
          "dataType":2
       },
       "address":{  
          "number":{  
         "attributeValue":"number",
         "attributeType":1,
         "dataType":1
          },
          "street":{  
         "attributeValue":"street",
         "attributeType":1,
         "dataType":1
          },
          "city":{  
         "attributeValue":"city",
         "attributeType":1,
         "dataType":1
          },
          "country":{  
         "attributeValue":"country",
         "attributeType":1,
         "dataType":1
          }
       },
       "fullName":{  
          "attributeValue":"#firstName.concat(' ').concat(#lastName)",
          "attributeType":2,
          "dataType":1
       }
    }
```

In here, each node that has attributeValue,dataType and attributeType nodes are called "Field". Every other parent node is a handler. "name" is a handler which has "first" and "last" fields. But for age, since there is no parent key, there should be a handler created named "age" and a field "age" should be added to that. Handlers can have handlers. Handlers have fields in them. Below is the Handler object representation.

```
  public interface Handler<T> {
     void addField(Field field);
     void addHandler(Handler handler);
     String getName();
     List<Field> getFields();
     T handle(T target);
 }
```

Below is the field representation.

```
 public interface Field<T> {
     void setValue(String value);
     T getField();
     String getFieldName();
 }
```

Now I need to parse the json schema and return a list of handlers. Below is what I tried.

```
 private List<Handler> parseJsonSchema(Handler handler, String jsonSchema) throws JSONMapperException {
        List<Handler> handlerList = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean isParentLeaf = false;
        Field<ObjectNode> objectNodeField = null;
        try {
            JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonSchema);
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> childrenIterator = rootNode.fields();
            while (childrenIterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = childrenIterator.next();
            System.out.println("Key: " + field.getKey() + "\tValue:" + field.getValue());
            if (field.getValue().has("attributeValue") && field.getValue().has("attributeType")
                    && field.getValue().has("dataType")) {
                if (handler == null) {
                    handler = jsonNodeHandlerFactory.create(field.getKey());
                    isParentLeaf = true;
                }
                JsonNode valueNode = field.getValue();
                //String fieldName = valueNode.get("attributeValue").toString();
                String fieldName = field.getKey();
                String dataType = valueNode.get("dataType").toString();
                switch (dataType) {
                    case "1":
                        objectNodeField = dataFieldFactory.createStringField(fieldName);
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        objectNodeField = dataFieldFactory.createIntField(fieldName);
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        objectNodeField = dataFieldFactory.createBooleanField(fieldName);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                handler.addField(objectNodeField);
                if(isParentLeaf) {
                    handlerList.add(handler);
                    handler =null;
                }
            } else {
                handler = jsonNodeHandlerFactory.create(field.getKey());
                List<Handler> handlers = parseJsonSchema(handler, field.getValue().toString());
                for (Handler handler1 : handlers) {
                    if(handler != null) { //means we already have a handler and we've come into another handler
                        handler.addHandler(handler1);
                        handlerList.add(handler);
                    } else {
                        handlerList.add(handler1);
                    }
                }
                handler = null;
            }
            if ((handler != null && handler.getFields().size() == rootNode.size())) {
                handlerList.add(handler);
            }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(JSON_SCHEMA_PARSE_EXCEPTION, e);
            throw new JSONMapperException(JSON_SCHEMA_PARSE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        return handlerList;
        }
```

But it overrides handlers, when there are handlers within handlers. Also it looks pretty clumsy with too many null assignments and if checks. Is there a better way to do what this method is already doing? That is return the schema as a list of handlers. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: so you gave up on json path?

Comment: wow you really have nothing to say about my answer... so why did you ask for help...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems to me that a better place for this question would be the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) forum.

However, to get you started, I have few tips:

1. As your intuition told you, the code indeed looks "clumsy" or, in other words, not implementing OO principles (or even just plain SW development ones) to good extent.
2. I would start by looking at the long branches of the if statememnt, making each branch into separate methods. something like `parseField()` and `parseHandler()` and perhaps there are other such blocks of code that can be isolated into separate methods. This will make the `parseJsonSchema()` method much more readable and debugable (this is, for instance, just plain SW development principle)
3. The abovementioned principle is aplicable not only in cases of long code blocks, but also in short ones that can be isolated and hide details for the sake of clarity: the if condition that determines if `field` is `Field` or `Handler`. Make it into `isField(Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry)` method. and perhaps you see now why naming it `field` is not the best option if it can be either `Field` or `Handler`. Same comment goes for the `handler1` variable. It must have a better more comprehensible name.
4. It is nice that you're using a factory to instantiate Fields.  However, other then calling the constructor for a concreate Field implementation, I fail to see what else is your factory doing, because all the parsing of the json and the decision making is done in the `parseJsonSchema()`. as a rule of thumb, the factory should have one method for each returned type (without generics). So, your factory is returning various `Field`s, then it should have just `createField()` that gets a `JsonNode` and parses what it needs to decide on which implementation to instantiate.
5. Another OO principle to follow: declare your variable in the inner-most scope that you can. `objectNodeField` is only accessed inside the branch that handles fields, so put the declaration inside the curly brackets of this branch. do not declare it in the scope of the whole `parseJsonSchema()`.  This makes it easier to understand the scope of the variable and avoid erroneous access outside of the applicable scope.

   Now, if you make the the branch into `parseField()` method, the `objectNodeField` variable becomes local to that new method. See how it makes the code better in terms of clarity and stability?
6. While we are looking at this variable, I am thinking why did you make its generic type `ObjectNode`, when its concrete variances are String, Integer and Boolean?
   how can `StringField` implement `handle()` method of `Field` interface and actually handle `ObjectNode` ? IMO, `objectNodeField` should be declared `Field<Object>` or better yet, `Field<?>` so it can host the abovementioned types.
7. It is nice that you're using recursion to parse the hierarchy of handlers and fields. However, you really think that parsing the Json String each time, and then re-packaging the tree back into String to call the next recursion is the best way?
8. I could go on but don't want to overwhelm you. Last note, I think you should get familiar with `Jackson`'s feature of parsing a Json String into a multi hierarchy `Map`. I think it is easier to traverse then Json Nodes.

Comment: wow you really have nothing to say about my answer... so why did you ask for help...

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply mate. I have made the changes you have specified. I have been looking into converting the logic with multi hierarchy map as you have advised. I have been waiting to let you know once I am done with that :) Should be over by this weekend

Comment: I have a small concern mate. While going with the map approach I still have to iterate each value and see if it has 3 specific attributes. If so I create a Field Object for that and if not   I create a Handler object for that. So still I have to iterate through the map elements and have a recursive method, shouldn't I? The level of complexity still seem to remain the same :(